# Issues with Fb App Domains and Site URL:

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, appdomain, fbconnect, fbjs

```
I am trying to integrate facebook connect to all my websites. 
For example I have a website called example.com and many sub domains 
like,
   bob.example.com,
   claire.second.example.com,
   swiss.example.com and so on. 
My objective was to use the same App ID to all the websites. 
Well I did find, as long as the base URL is the same 
(i.e in my case example.com) we can use the same App Id for all 
the websites. So I put example.com in my Site URL and the remaining domain 
names in the App Domains field. But when I compile the code, the fb connect works 
only for the Site URL and not the App domains. BTW I am using the example in this
following link,
```

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/
    Kindly Let me know if someone knows the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

- The issue was I was using localhost for testing(localhost doesn't work).
- And also include all the domains with the base URL being the same in the APP domain field to get them working.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTAPPID&redirect_uri=SITEURL(OR)APPDOMAINURL&response_type=token

Replace the above URL with your client id and the site url to check if it works rather than implementing FB JS SDK code in your site.